Aligning frequencies
Let $\omega_1, \omega_2, \dots, \omega_n$ be frequencies between $1$ and $\log n$. I would like to find an upper bound for a point $t$ that align these frequencies up to a small error $\delta$, that is,
$$ t \omega_i \in 2\pi \mathbb{Z} + (-\delta, \delta)$$
for all $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$.
The term $\log n$ could be relaxed. Although this feels classical, I tried to find similar results but couldn't. I'd appreciate if anyone can point me to a direction on how to approach this. Thank you!

Can't you use the simultaneous version of Dirichlet's approximation theorem with $\frac{\omega_i}{2\pi}$? It gives $(\frac{2\pi}{\delta})^n$, I think, and doesn't need an upper bound on the frequencies.

Oh, your $t$ doesn't have to be an integer, right? So while Dirichlet's approximation theorem gives an upper bound, there might be a much smaller one

You can think of the problem as finding $n_i$s such that $\frac {n_i}{ \omega_i}$ are approximately all the same. This means $\frac{n_i}{n_1} \approx \frac{\omega_1}{\omega_i}$, and now you can apply Dirichlet's approximation theorem to get an exponent of $n-1$ instead of $n$ (although you need to keep track of the error to make this formal). This seems mostly two directional, so I don't expect you can do much better
